# jquery remove a class from everywhere is it exists

Tags: jquery, class, removeclass

I'm trying to remove a class `e` from everywhere is it exists.

For more details, please check my code: https://jsfiddle.net/gf4a27nn/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">
  <button class="b d">button</button>
</div>
<div id="c" class="d">content</div>
<div id="f">content2</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("button.b").on("click", function() {
    $(".d").addClass("e");
  })

  $(".e").on("click", function() {
    $(".d").removeClass("e");
  })
})
```

Comment: In the CSS, your `.d.e {}` should be: `.d, .e {}` if you want the style to apply to both classes. Might need to switch to `.bind()` to remove `e` class after it has been added. Or in the first click, search for `e` class and remove it. Could also use `.toggle()`

Comment: For some reason I cant do $(".e").on("click", function() { alert("hi") })"

Answer (score 5):

To remove the class `e` from everywhere where it exists, use:

```
$('.e').removeClass('e');
```

Comment: thx, but a problem is onclick. For some reason I cant do $(".e").on("click", function() { alert("hi") })"

Answer (score 0):

See working example of what I commented about: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/gf4a27nn/2/

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("button.b").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".e").length) {
      $(".e").removeClass("e");
    } else {
      $(".d").addClass("e");
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: It's not happening when I click to content1 "id=c".

Answer (score 0):

You are adding only '.e' in onclick event. jquery unable to find your attribute. so, You should use like "div#a button.e".

```
$(function() {
    $("button.b").on("click", function() {
   //remove this line. because you are having class 'd' for button and div 
   //$(".d").addClass("e");
   // to addClass 'e' for button use below code,
   $(this).addClass("e");
  })

  // now use onclick function for class 'e'
  $("div#a button.e").on("click", function() {
    alert("button class removal");
    $(this).removeClass("e");
  })

})
```